# How to use CustomAdapter with ListView from XML Async Task

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-asynctask, custom-adapter

I achieved populate a **ListView** using **StringBuilder** from a Internet XML Source.

With this code the listView is populated with only one String but I want populate the listview by elements: **getIdLine** and **getTimeLeft** (With **CustomAdapter**) for customize the layout of the listView items in separated Strings.

How to achieve this?

*EDITED CODE*

`FragmentActivity.class`

```
private ListView listViewEMT;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> yourList;

... AsyncTask

 protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
            super.onPostExecute(string);
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), yourList);
            listViewEMT.setAdapter(adapter);
            this.progressDialog.dismiss();


        }

 /** RSS HANDLER CLASS */


    class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

        StringBuffer chars;
        private Arrival currentArrival;

        RSSHandler() {
            this.currentArrival = new Arrival();
            this.chars = new StringBuffer();
        }

        public void characters(char[] arrc, int n, int n2) {
            this.chars.append(new String(arrc, n, n2));
        }

        public void endElement(String string, String string2, String string3) throws SAXException {
            super.endElement(string, string2, string3);
            if ((string2.equalsIgnoreCase("idStop")) && (this.currentArrival.getIdStop() == null)) {
                this.currentArrival.setIdStop(this.chars.toString());
            }
            if ((string2.equalsIgnoreCase("idLine")) && (this.currentArrival.getIdLinea() == null)) {
                this.currentArrival.setIdLinea(this.chars.toString());
            }
            if ((string2.equalsIgnoreCase("TimeLeftBus")) && (this.currentArrival.getTimeLeft() == 0)) {
                int n = Integer.valueOf((String)(this.chars.toString()));
                this.currentArrival.setTimeLeft(n);
            }
            if (!(string2.equalsIgnoreCase("Arrive"))) return;
            yourList.add((HashMap<String, String>)(currentArrival.getMap()));
            this.currentArrival = new Arrival();
        }

        public void startElement(String string, String string2, String string3, org.xml.sax.Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            super.startElement(string, string2, string3, attributes);
            this.chars = new StringBuffer();
            string2.equalsIgnoreCase("Arrive");
        }

    }
```

`Arrival.class`

```
...getters and setters
 public HashMap<String, String> getMap() {

        HashMap<String, String> map;
        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put("KEY1", idLinea);
        map.put("KEY2", String.valueOf(timeLeft));



        return map;

    }
```

`CustomAdapter.class` Thanks to Nabin

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private List<String> listString;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.emt_item, null);

        TextView tv1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.itemLine);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.itemTime);
        HashMap<String, String> map;
        map = data.get(position);
        tv1.setText(map.get("KEY1"));
        tv2.setText(map.get("KEY2"));
        return vi;
    }

}
```

Comment: What have you got till now? Have you tried anything? Is there any error? @makgyverzx

Comment: @Nabin I tried create an ArrayList but now, I'm having problems with generateData() and return items. Edited Code in Question

Comment: Do you have your custom adapter?

Comment: What is your listLlegadas type?

Comment: @Nabin It's an ArrayList `private ArrayList<Object> listLlegadas;`

Comment: why do you have "(List)listLlegadas"? as last parameter?

Comment: It was my first attempt which populate the listView with an only String. I don't know what kind of changes I need to do to use CustomAdapter

Comment: remove "(List)" and see.

Comment: Removing `(List)` the listView is populated, but with an only String, The CustomAdapter doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom adapter as following:

```
public class ArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
private List<String> listString;

public ArrayAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
//your getView method here
}
```

**GetView Method**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);

        TextView tv1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvone);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvtwo);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map = data.get(position);
        tv1.setText(map.get("KEY1"));
        tv2.setText(map.get("KEY2"));
        return vi;
    }
```

Make array list as:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> yourList;
```

And fill **yourList** as

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
// adding each child node to HashMap key => value
map.put("KEY1", value1);
map.put("KEY2", value2);
yourList.add(map);
```

And while making object of the custom adapter

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(YourActivity.this, yourList);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

For **list** you can do

```
list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, It's almost done. I'm having some problems: ArrayList needs to be created from Arrival.class (nonActivity, has setters and getters) and accessed from FragmentActivity.class. `yourList` Appears as not initialized and the return of `map` need to be ArrayList but is HashMap. So many thanks for your help!

Comment: Hello again mate, I solved everything except when I'm setting the ArrayAdapter in `FragmentActivity()` which is a non-activity class, the first parameter is an activity, but when I'm trying to put MainActivity.this my IDE says "MainActivity is not an enclosing class". Could you help me? What can I do?

Comment: try getActivity() n tell me of u hab further problem

Comment: The code works without problems, but ListView is not populated with items. I have edited my question with code changes.

Comment: Show how you have got yourList

Comment: yourList is filled with the HashMap calling method getMap() wich returns the HashMap from Arrival.class in RSSHANDLER from FragmentActivity.class

Comment: Try to generate dummy HashMap in PostExecute and hence list to see if it works.

Comment: CustomAdapter.class is the problem. I'll check it out another day. I solved it using SimpleListAdapter using values from HashMap:
`String[] from = new String[] { "KEY1", "KEY2", "KEY3"};
            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.itemLine, R.id.itemTime, R.id.itemDestination};
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), yourList, R.layout.emt_item, from, to);`