# Get available wi-fi scan result in customized listview

Tags: android, android-listview, wifi, wifimanager

I want a available  wifi scan result in a customized listview on start of activity. But i want to show only SSID and Allowed key Management and the strength of network same as android phone shows when we check wifi list in it.

```
package com.am.wifi.amitwifi;

import java.util.List;

import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
       WifiManager mainWifiObj;
       WifiScanReceiver wifiReciever;
       ListView list;
       String wifis[];


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
          mainWifiObj = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
          wifiReciever = new WifiScanReceiver();
          mainWifiObj.startScan();

    }
       protected void onPause() {
              unregisterReceiver(wifiReciever);
              super.onPause();
           }

       protected void onResume() {
              registerReceiver(wifiReciever, new IntentFilter(
              WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
              super.onResume();
           }
       class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
              @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
              public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
                 List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();
                 wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
                 for(int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++){
                    wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i)).toString());
                 }

                 list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,wifis));
              }
           }
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I am just getting a list of available wi-fi with all the details. Like SSID, BSSID, RSSID, allowed Key mamangment etc

Comment: Thanks for the edit, please wait

Comment: @NAbin Your Welcome Okay i am waiting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following after your loop

```
String filtered[] = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
            int counter = 0;
            for (String eachWifi : wifis) {
                String[] temp = eachWifi.split(",");
                filtered[counter] = temp[0] +temp[2] +temp[3];//0->SSID, 2->Key Management 3-> Strength
                counter++;
            }
            list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, filtered));
```

To remove extra words you can do the following:

```
temp[0].substring(5).trim()
```

This removes the first 5 characters and trims any whitespace. Do similar to others as well. And use `\n` to get on next line.

**Or best idea would be use custom adapter.
See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457812/how-to-use-customadapter-with-listview-from-xml-async-task)**

Good luck.

Comment: because on my device it showing error... App unfortunately stopped

Comment: Its working fine but i want jus the SSID and capabilities below SSID eg.ABC                                                                 [Wap etc]        instead of SSID:ABC etc can you help me reagrding this

Comment: I have checked the code on console. Means I have made sure the **filtered** array contains proper data

Comment: You want to display on next line?

Comment: Yes i want to display on next line also want remoove the SSID and capabilities word before SSID and key managment

Comment: OK wait for a minute.

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck for future

Comment: i need your help. i want to filter the list of wi-fi with the SSID mean i want to display only specific SSID wi-fi into the list. Please Help me